# Product cdn image path issue

Tags: import, image, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm importing images from another store that are already on a CDN. I've set the config>web Base Media URLs to the CDN for both Secure/Unsecure. When I look at the products in admin, I get a broken image. When I check the html, the "onmouseover" event has the correct url in parenthesis, but the img tag has a "catalog/product/" path imbedded in between the CDN and the  image path. When I mouseover, the console shows it trying to fetch the invalid path with the "catalog/product/" path.

mouseover: https://cdn.foo.com/products/images/1/1.jpg

img tag source: https://cdn.foo.com/catalog/product/products/images/1/1.jpg

Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing so I can just get my image or do I have to mess with the skin?